# C# resolving DNS aliases for a host

Tags: c#

I'm trying to query the DNS server for DNS aliases (CNAME records) and gethostentry always returns no aliases.  Which I believe is explained by MSDN ("The Aliases property of the IPHostEntry instance returned is not populated by this method and will always be empty.")

So the question is, how do I get the aliases for my code?

```
 IPAddress hostIPAddress = IPAddress.Parse("192.168.1.2");
 IPHostEntry myHost = Dns.GetHostEntry(hostIPAddress);

 String[] myAliases = myHost.Aliases;
```

Comment: possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1474612/querying-for-dns-aliases