# .NET GetHostByAddress aliases only showing up 8 entries

Tags: c#, .net, powershell, dns

I need to get every CNAME record out from a single IP address input from our DNS server.

When I lookup:

```
[System.Net.Dns]::GetHostByAddress("81.95.243.81").Aliases
```

It only gives me the same 8 aliases in return:

```
botexshop.dk
bisamba.dk
nordsoenoceanarium.dk
www.brandingcommunity.com
botexhome.dk
botexudstyr.dk
botexjylland.dk
marineacademy.dk
```

but I know that the IP address has over 69 CNAME records (please look here: [Toolbox | DNSstuff | Reverse DNS Lookup Results for 81.95.243.81](http://www.dnsstuff.com/tools#reverseDns/type=ipv4&&value=81.95.243.81&&) )

Why does the `GetHostByAddress` only return the same 8 aliases all the time? And how do I get all the CNAMEs ?

Comment: GetHostBYAddress is Obsolete: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/sbetxfzt.aspx

Comment: I know, but GetHostEntry doesn't return any aliases at all..
[System.Net.Dns]::GetHostEntry("81.95.243.81").Aliases returns nothing. So how can I benefit from your answer?

Comment: it's not an answer: it's clearly a comment.

Comment: Since I can't downwote comments, I downwoted the question - I believe it's _wrong_ to make fun of someone trying to help you.

Answer (score 0):

System.Net.Dns is quite lacking in many ways. I've seen some people go as far as writing full-blown DNS parsers to get what they need.

I know this doesn't fully answer your question, but this function seems to get the job done, however it's quite fragile and relies on nslookup so YMMV:

```
function get-dnsaliases($ip)
{
    $ip_rev = $ip -split '\.'
    [array]::reverse($ip_rev)
    $ip_rev = $ip_rev -join '.'
    $ptr_regex = "^`t" + [regex]::escape("$ip_rev.in-addr.arpa, type = PTR, class = IN")

    $responses = nslookup -d $ip

    $foundanswer = $null
    $aliases = @()

    foreach ($response in $responses)
    {
        if($foundanswer)
        {
            if($response -match "^`tname = (?<alias>.+)$")
            {
                $aliases += $Matches.alias
            }
        }
        elseif($response -match $ptr_regex)
        {
            $foundanswer = $true
        }
    }
    return $aliases
}
```