# What is the nslookup equivalent in C#?

Tags: dns, system.net, nslookup

I want to get the aliases that is returned by nslookup as below:

```
F:\>nslookup maans20210630125234.sandbox.operations.test.dynamics.com

Server:   UnKnown
Address:  2001:4898::1050:1050
Non-authoritative answer:
Name:    apimgmths6q7kyczcrkpvds6u99ofw4apdrqgxc8s7qavl14wy.cloudapp.net
Address: 52.188.3.251

Aliases:  maans20210630125234.sandbox.operations.test.dynamics.com
          d365-ops-dev-gwy-eastus-eus2-2.azure-api.net
          apimgmttm0hgnv1tmdyrtilrp0hcvphjwrq4gtyzzfdqehnzfn.trafficmanager.net
          d365-ops-dev-gwy-eastus-eus2-2-eastus-01.regional.azure-api.net
```

[nslookup](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OTMPT.png)

I want equivalent of above in c sharp. I already tried `Dns.GetHostEntry`. It does not return aliases as mentioned in official document. How do I get the aliases in C# / .NET?

[Dns.GetHostEntry(hostNameOrAddress)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/B4hPF.png)

Comment: Hope this answer will help you out
https://stackoverflow.com/a/17575503/4356387

Answer (score -2):

"Aliases" are DNS `CNAME` records. So you need to find out how to query for DNS `CNAME` records from your DNS library. You probably need to use a low level DNS library that lets you control all low level details of a DNS query, because high level calls like `GetHostEntry` are designed to just give you the final answer and hiding the intermediate steps (the `CNAME` chain resolution).

On the command line the equivalent are:

```
$ dig maans20210630125234.sandbox.operations.test.dynamics.com +short
d365-ops-dev-gwy-eastus-eus2-2.azure-api.net.
apimgmttm0hgnv1tmdyrtilrp0hcvphjwrq4gtyzzfdqehnzfn.trafficmanager.net.
d365-ops-dev-gwy-eastus-eus2-2-eastus-01.regional.azure-api.net.
apimgmths6q7kyczcrkpvds6u99ofw4apdrqgxc8s7qavl14wy.cloudapp.net.
52.188.3.251
```

This follows all the intermediate CNAME and gives you the final IP address (as `dig` does `A` record type queries by default)

But if you specify record type `CNAME` you get only the first answer (and hence you will have to do yourself a loop to find out all intermediate CNAME until you get an error or the final answer):

```
$ dig maans20210630125234.sandbox.operations.test.dynamics.com CNAME +short
d365-ops-dev-gwy-eastus-eus2-2.azure-api.net.
```