# Why `getaddrinfo` doesn't support aliases?

Tags: dns, alias, cname, getaddrinfo, gethostbyname

Unlike [`gethostbyname`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/gethostbyname.3.html), the function [`getaddrinfo`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/getaddrinfo.3.html) does not return a list of alias names for a hostname. What was the reason to not include this information in the `getaddrinfo` result?

I searched for a reference to this decision in:

- [IETF mail archive](https://mailarchive.ietf.org/arch/search/?q=getaddrinfo+alias)
- [RFC-3493 Basic Socket Interface Extensions for IPv6](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3493)
- [Beej's Guide to Network Programming](https://beej.us/guide/bgnet/html/#getaddrinfoprepare-to-launch)

But couldn't find a answer to this question. The answer possibly is because it's anyway [not possible to get *all* aliases for a name](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1474643). Is this the answer or where there other considerations please share your knowledge.